# How to cancel a mapped Observable with specify condition at RxScala/Java?

Tags: rx-java, observable, rx-scala

original observable ------a-------b-------c----------d-------->....
mapped observable   -----A-------B(finish)
Simple code as this:

```
  val original = Observable.just('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
  val mapped = original.map(x => x.toUpper)
  //how to let `mapped` Observable stop emit event when received 'b' from original?
  //do something
  mapped.subscribe(x => println(x)) //make it only print A ,B
```

How to make mapped observable finished at `B` this specify condition?

**UPDATE for takeUntil method**
`takeUntil` seems a standard answer but my editer shows this method take `Observable[Any]` as paramter.See definition please,
`def takeUntil(that: Observable[Any]): Observable[T]`

if I use follows code

```
  val original = Observable.just('a', 'b', 'c', 'd').takeUntil(x => x == 'b')
```

a compile error occurred

```
Error:(74, 64) missing parameter type
  val original = Observable.just('a', 'b', 'c', 'd').takeUntil(x => x == 'b')
                                                           ^
```

Does we use a same package? my sbt dependency is   `"com.netflix.rxjava" % "rxjava-scala" % "0.20.7"`

Comment: `original.takeUntil(x => x == 'b').map(..).subscribe(..)`

Comment: @peeskillet, yours is very different with my definition of `takeUntil` method.It's very awkward ... I have update the trouble to my question.See again please.

Comment: I think it is the version. I am looking at the javadoc for rx-java, and it says the [`takUntil(Func predicate)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#takeUntil%28rx.functions.Func1%29) is not untroduced until 1.1.0. I guess `takeUntil(Observable)` is an older method. I don't know how that version matches up with rx-scala version, I have never used rx.scala

Comment: Looking at the [latest 0.26](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#takeUntil%28rx.functions.Func1%29), it does have the predicate version, but it has a experimental annotation.

Comment: @peeskillet, I have update to 0.26, it works well~thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `takeWhile`, it does exactly what you need.

Comment: I'd say [`takeUntil`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#takeUntil%28rx.functions.Func1%29). With [`takeWhile`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#takeWhile%28rx.functions.Func1%29), you wont get `B`, assuming the condition is `x == B`

Comment: Whops ; Correct, he wants to finish on B condition, not on C condition.

Comment: Hi, I have seem [thsi diagram](http://rxmarbles.com/#takeUntil) but I still don't know how to use it.can you give me a use case?thanks

Comment: @LoranceChen it's actually `takeWhile` - `takeUntil` needs a second observable.

Comment: the latest version seems needn't.do you means the latest version is wrapped a observable we just can't see straightly?

Comment: No, I mean that `takeWhile` operates on a single observable (the end condition comes from the original observable), while `takeUntil` operates on two (the end condition comes from the second observable).